# display image on static control win32 with scrollbar

Tags: winapi, bitmap, scrollbar

is it possible to make a static control (win32) has `SS_BITMAP | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL`?

All I want to do is just to load a bitmap on a fixed size Static Control and if the image size is bigger than control's size, it can be scrolled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you *tried* it ? (and last I checked, [no](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773(v=vs.85).aspx), but its been awhile).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks for your reply Craig, yes i have tried it and the program crashes. Is there any way to make such static control?

Comment: Not that I know of using native win32 statics. Statics are, by their nature, not-interactive, somewhat killing the proposal of interactive scrollbars in the first place. it would be akin to putting scrollbars on a label.

Comment: Scrolling content is not natively supported by static controls. You will have to respond to the scroll messages yourself and reposition the content.

Comment: @Craig and Chen: So, I have to create 3 controls, 1 static with `SS_BITMAP` and 2 scrollbars ?

Comment: I wouldn't use a static at all for this. I'd likely just use an ownerdraw control with appropriate scrollbar styles, establish the scroll limits to be the non-visible portion (in pixels) of the bitmap sizing, and BitBlt() as-needed in a paint handler based on the scroller positions. There are samples of how to do this in almost every Windows Programming book I've ever seen, including the mac-daddy of all of them: Petzold.

Comment: @Craig: Would you like to tell me some clues how to do that?

Comment: @Chen: After searching, I think you want me to subclass the static control. Here what I got :
`StWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLong(hImg, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)StaticWndProc);`

where StWndProc is global `WNDPROC` variable, hImg is my static control with `WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL`, and StaticWndProc was declared as `LRESULT CALLBACK`. In the StaticWndProc I try to catch some messages (ie: `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`) and display a message, but the messages was never showed. Any ideas? Thanks.